# A bounded sequence in $l^1$ which does not admit a weak convergent subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I saw several examples for bounded sequences in $L^1$ which do not admit a weak convergent subsequence.
But what about $l^1$ the sequence space?

Comment: This should help: https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/an-elementry-proof-of-schurs-theorem/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical Schauder basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ does not admit any weakly convergent subsequence.

By the way, observe that weakly convergent sequences in $\ell_1$, by the Schur property, are the same as norm convergent ones.